# Error injecting a script in others tabs in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

this is my first try building a chrome extension.
I took the first example and motified it to my needs.

I want to build a chrome extension that can controll the youtube player on different tabs
from the popup menu.

At first i want to show a list of all open youtube tabs. This works fine.
After that i want to insert a script in each of those tabs.

Thats where the problem occurs:
The developer console gives me the following error

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.      sendRequest:22
    chromeHidden.handleResponse                      sendRequest:22
Callback worked
```

My manifest.json looks like this

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "YoutubeMusicControl",
  "description": "First Try",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

The popup.html does nothing special besides running the script.

Here is the interesting part

```
var TabControl = {

    listCurrentTabs : function(){
        var name = "";
        var div;

        chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){

            for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){

                var found = tabs[i].url.search(/.*youtube.*/);

                if(found != -1){
                    div = document.createElement('div');

                    name = tabs[i].title;
                    div.className = "entry";
                    div.innerHTML = name;
                    document.body.appendChild(div);                  

                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(i,{
                        code:"alert('test');"
                    },function(results){console.log("Callback worked")});
                    }                    
                }
        });
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  TabControl.listCurrentTabs();
});
```

If i change the parameter i to null (the current tab), everythings works fine.
It looks as if i dont have the permisson or something is wrong with the parameter,
but i cant get the code to work.

Can somebody see why the code is not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer lies in the parameters of `executeScript`. If you do not speciy a `tabID`, it defaults to your current active tab (this is what happens when you feed it `null`).

However, when you feed it that optional integer, you need to be aware that this integer is **not** the index of the tab in the tablist, but its actual ID (can be acquired using `tab[i].id` in your case).

Using the unique ID of the tab will make your code work. Just change `executeScript(i` to `executeScript(tabs[i].id`

Comment: Thanks, that was the Problem. :) 
Can be so easy... Have a great day!